# Show block only for certain roles

Tags: symfony, block, roles, symfony-sonata

Is there a way to configure a block in Sonata Admin Bundle/Sonata Block Bundle, in order to display it only for users with certain roles?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [`RecentOrdersBlockService`](https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce/blob/develop/src/OrderBundle/Block/RecentOrdersBlockService.php#L76), you may specify a `mode` variable and have a dedicated treatment depending on that. Moreover, you may retrieve the user from the `securityContext` and vary your treatment depending on that.